# Mean procedure with SAS

Tags: sas

I want to find the mean of following datalines;
the way I am trying, I am getting the mean based on no. of observation which in this case is 6. But I want it based on Day so it comes something like Mean = Timeread/(no. of day) which is 3

```
name    Day    Timeread
X        1        12
X        1        23
X        1        12
X        2        8
X        2        5
X        3        3
```

This is the code I used

```
proc summary data = xyz nway missing;
  class Name;
  var timeread;
  output out = Average mean=;
run;
proc print data = Average;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do this with `proc mean` but you can do this in SQL like so:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table want as
  select name, 
         sum(timeread) / count(distinct day) as daily_mean
  from have
  group by name
  ;
quit;
```

This uses the HAVE dataset from @CarolinaJay65's answer.

Comment: Yes, That is the output I want but using proc summary or proc mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting the mean of total timeread by total distinct days

```
Data HAVE;
Input name $   Day  Timeread ;
Datalines;
X        1        12
X        1        23
X        1        12
X        2        8
X        2        5
X        3        3 
;
Run;

Proc Sql;
    Create table WANT as
    Select Name, (select count(distinct(Day)) from HAVE) as DAYS
     , sum(timeread) as TIMEREAD_TOTAL
     , calculated timeread_total/calculated days as MEAN
    From HAVE
    Group by Name;
Quit;
```

Comment: No, this give me output in following format
    `Name    Timeread`

   ` X             (12+23+12)/3`

    `X              (8+5)/2`

   ` X               (3/1)`
Instead I want

   ` X            (12+23+12+8+5+3)/3`


P.S sorry not being able to put it in code format so it's easy to understand